# Need help creating a temporary function

Tags: sql

I have a table with a column name 'sub_org'. It has hundreds of rows. The column contains the values ("Regional Team Americas", "Regional Team EMEA", and "Regional Team APAC").

I need to create a temporary function so that it replaces the values in that column with "AMER", "EMEA", or "APAC"

Comment: Like a case expression? `SELECT CASE WHEN sub_org = 'Regional Team Americas' THEN 'AMER' WHEN sub_org = 'Regional Team EMEA' THEN 'EMEA' WHEN sub_org = 'Regional Team APAC' THEN 'APAC' END AS sub_org_abbr FROM yourtable;`. or `DECODE()` (if your RDBMS, which you didn't specify, supports the function): `SELECT DECODE(sub_org, 'Regional Team Americas', 'AMER', 'Regional Team EMEA', 'EMEA', 'Regional Team APAC', 'APAC') as sub_org_abbr FROM yourtable;`

Comment: Yes, I'm going to be needing this function a lot so I needed to create a temporary function that serves this purpose. So I can use this `SELECT SomeFunction(sub_org) AS sub_org_abbr FROM table`

Comment: Is there any reason why it needs to be a function vs a Case Expression like I suggested above? Why reinvent the wheel? If there are more values than just the three, then a function still wouldn't be the right solution, and instead a separate table with `sub_org | abbr` columns would be more appropriate, to which you would join your existing table.